# Database encoding information provided by QGIS is wrong (windows-1252 instead of UTF8)

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qfield, windows-10, encoding

I have a [PostgreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) (13.9)/[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) (3.1.1) layer in a [QGIS](https://qgis.org/) project (tested on 3.16, 3.20 and 3.22 with same results). The actual database [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is [`UTF8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), but the "Information" tab in the layer properties is showing me: "Encoding: [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)":

[image]

I also checked from QGIS, using the following SQL command (`SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;`) in the DB manager, that the encoding is indeed `UTF8`:

[image]

Same goes for: `SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;` -> `UTF8`.

Hence my question: why is the "information from provider" wrong about the database encoding then?

This windows-1252 encoding is causing me some troubles when I try to upload the QGIS project on an Android device running the latest [QField](https://qfield.org).

As it's written "Information from Provider", I guess I cannot change whatever *from* QGIS.

##### Information

The operating system is Windows 10 and I'm connecting to the database through an SSH tunnel using a postgres service file on the local machine.

The database is running on an Ubuntu 20.04 server.

Beside that, everything is working fine. [PgAdmin4](https://pgadmin.org/) also shows me `UTF8` as the database encoding along with `LC_COLLATE = 'C'` and `LC_CTYPE = 'C'`

Comment: Does `SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;` return `windows-1252`?

Comment: Same goes for `SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;` -> `UTF8`. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: This might be more suitable as a bug report